# gapi.auth.authorize: Error: _.Uu is not a function

Tags: google-oauth

My web application started to error out yesterday when calling gapi.auth.authorize, and there is no code change. Below is the error stack:

> Error: *.Uu is not a function
>   mk@/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.1gq98XyFUlU.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTPj42_xcRHRghwn4h4H79TdCPg3pw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:234">https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.1gq98XyFUlU.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTPj42_xcRHRghwn4h4H79TdCPg3pw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:234
>   qA@/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.1gq98XyFUlU.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTPj42_xcRHRghwn4h4H79TdCPg3pw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:236">https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.1gq98XyFUlU.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTPj42_xcRHRghwn4h4H79TdCPg3pw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:236
>   *.sk@/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.1gq98XyFUlU.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTPj42_xcRHRghwn4h4H79TdCPg3pw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:238">https://apis.google.com//scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.1gq98XyFUlU.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTPj42_xcRHRghwn4h4H79TdCPg3pw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:238

Is anyone seeing the same problem? Not sure if Google is making any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Google broke the JS client yesterday. It's being tracked here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=103